# What is the best way to get the traceback object for an exception?

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is get the `__traceback__` object and some information from it, for printing out a custom view of the exception information.

Should I use:

- `e.__traceback__` ?
- `sys.exc_info()[2]` ?
- something else I don't know of?

Furthermore, once I have the `__traceback__` object, does it matter how I pull things out of it (line number, file name, etc.)? Various sources suggest different approaches to accomplish the same thing:

- Use the `traceback` module, give it the traceback, then use its `StackSummary`, `FrameSummary`, and other convoluted calls and objects to get the info.
- Get the traceback with `sys.exc_info()[2]`, but access the fields manually: `tb.tb_lineno` for the line number, for example.
- Something else?

Is it a "bad idea" to just pull everything from the exception object? Is there a danger in doing so? Doesn't it encapsulate all the info about the exception already?

In other words, are there any good reasons against doing this:

```python
except Exception as e:
    error_file = e.__traceback__.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
    error_line = e.__traceback__.tb_lineno
    # Other exception fields that I may want to print out
```